# Python2 print postgresql stored procedure raise notice

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

How can I print postgres's stored procedure on python script?

Example of stored procedure in postgres is as below:

```
create or replace function checktime() returns void
language plpgsql
as $$
DECLARE timestart TIMESTAMP;

  FOR id from rt LOOP
    SELECT timeofday() into timestart;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Time now : %', timestart;
  END LOOP;

END;
$$
;
```

From python, my script is:

```
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(host="", database="", 
user="", password="")
print("Database Connected")
cur = conn.cursor()
rowcount = cur.rowcount

cur.callproc('rt_visits_function_gz')
# how can i display the raise notice in here?
```

I would like for each loop the result is displayed when i run python.

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using 'notices'

print(conn.notices)

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/connection.html?highlight=notice#connection.notices

Comment: notice that if you are using something like SQLAlchemy, then you need to access `conn.connection.notices` where `connection` refers to a SQLAlchemy Connection instance attribute that holds the actual psycopg2 connection.