# Getting results and explain analyze output at the same time from Postgresql by running the statement once

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Is there any way to execute the statement once and get the results as well as explain analyze output? I don't want to run SQL for example, get the results, and then add `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to the beginning of the statement and run it again for explain plan. If there is something in the **psycopg2** package, that would be great.

One way - to activate **auto_explain** and parse the logs. But maybe there is a better idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have superuser access, you can use `auto_explain` to get the results in the client session:

```
test=# LOAD 'auto_explain';
LOAD
test=# SET log_min_messages = PANIC;  -- don't log it
SET
test=# SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
SET
test=# SET auto_explain.log_analyze = on;
SET
test=# SET auto_explain.log_buffers = on;
SET
test=# SET client_min_messages = LOG;
SET
test=# SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION laurenz;
SET

test=> SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'pg_class';
LOG:  duration: 0.040 ms  plan:
Query Text: SELECT oid FROM pg_class WHERE relname = 'pg_class';
Index Scan using pg_class_relname_nsp_index on pg_class  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.019..0.021 rows=1 loops=1)
  Index Cond: (relname = 'pg_class'::name)
  Buffers: shared hit=3
 oid  
------
 1259
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But when I try to do it with python **psycopg2** package `cursor.fetchall()` returns only result which is 1259, not the log

Comment: Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50275423/6464308) for how to get NOTICE messages.